# MAXVALUE partition filled

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have date ranged partitioning in Mysql db, but did not create enough partitions to hold data. Eventually MAXVALUE partition started filling up, and has 100M records.

How do I fix this and split it to weekly partitions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ALTER TABLE ... REORGANIZE PARTITION` to rewrite one or more partitions into a new set of partitions.

There is documentation and examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html